# Restore single database (or table-space) using PITR with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, backup, recovery, write-ahead-logging

Is there any possibility restore a single database with WAL files.

Comment: Don't think so -- I would restore everything to a new cluster and then export the single database (or tablespace).

Comment: [pgBackRest](https://pgbackrest.org) can [restore](https://pgbackrest.org/command.html#command-restore) only specified databases. Actually it restores all cluster but the unwanted databases are created with zero sized files. After restore you should drop the zero databases manually.